# Bitlocker Performance Hit around 60%?

Tags: bitlocker

I enabled 128 bit AES Bitlocker on my machine expecting to take a single digit performance hit on read/write time (based on what I had read online).

However, with ATTO Disk Benchmark I am seeing a ~60% on write and uneven performance on read, but often exceeding single digits.

I have noticed that during the benchmark Windows 10 seems to only be using one core do to encryption, and the results look CPU bound to me. Is there a switch somewhere that I can flip that will let me throw 4 or 6 cores at this?

I am using an i7-6820HK skylake cpu.

Here is my OS drive performance without Bitlocker:

[image]

Here is my OS drive performance with Bitlocker:

[image]